# Gazebo world file from a collada file

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users,

I created a collada file of a terrain using *Blender* and now I want it to be included in a *Gazebo* .world file. How is this done?

Thanks in advance

CS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10899/gazebo-world-file-from-a-collada-file/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2011-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the files world/wg_collada.world and launch/wg_collada_world.launch in the gazebo_worlds package. They load a map from a collada file.

The code in question is:

```
<model:physical name="willow_map">
   <xyz>-33.0 -15.0 0</xyz>
   <rpy>0 0 0</rpy>
   <static>true</static>
   <body:trimesh name="willow_map_body">
     <geom:trimesh name="willow_map_geom">
       <scale>0.02 0.02 0.02</scale>
       <mesh>willowgarage.dae</mesh>
       <visual>
         <scale>0.02 0.02 0.02</scale>
         <mesh>willowgarage.dae</mesh>
       </visual>
     </geom:trimesh>
   </body:trimesh>
  </model:physical>
```

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2011-09-11**:
Thanks for your answer hsu.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-02**:
gzbuilder has not been kept up-to-date.  How big is your terrain file (faces/vertices)?  Make sure the scale is correct (default view suitable for meters).  Take a look at http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/GazeboConfiguration for where to put the meshes.

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2011-08-15**:
Actually, in Gazebo there is a terrain builder utility called gzbuilder. But it seems like it does not exist in ROS Gazebo. That is why I went for collada files. If anyone can shed light on how to build a simple terrain, it would be really appreciated. Thanks

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2011-08-15**:
Thank you for your answer. I already looked at it but I do not know why my terrain model is not loaded. Is there any special way of creating the collada file ?(for e.g. to check some kind of options when I export)
One more thing. Do we have to copy the .dae file into gazebo share folder? Can't we just have it on a user specified location?

Thank you in advance.